# cant seem to get the '.focus();' element to work...

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As the title suggests I can't seem to get '.focus();'to work.
And have no clue why, as far as I can tell it should be working just fine?

I want it so that when the 'ok' button of the alert is pressed the cursor will be ready to type in the 'userName' text box.

Thank you in advance. Code Below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Com 311 | Week 9</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function validName(){

            var Name = document.userSurvey.userName.value;

            if (Name=="")
            {
                alert ("Please enter your name.");
                document.getElementById('userName').focus();
            }

        }

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> User Survey </h1>
        <hr />
        <h2> User Information </h2>
        <h3>Please enter your details below:</h3>

    <form name="userSurvey" onsubmit="validName()">
        <p> Full Name: (required) </p>
        <input type="text" size="30" name="userName"/>


        <p> Email Address: (required) </p>
        <input type="text" size="50" name="email"/>


        <p> Phone Number: (required)</p>
        <input type="number" size="30" name="phone"/>

        <hr />

        <p> Please choose your favourite type of book:</p>

        <input type="checkbox" name="bookChoice0" value="Action">Action 
        <input type="checkbox" name="bookChoice1" value="Comic">Comic
        <input type="checkbox" name="bookChoice2" value="Adventure">Adventure 
        <input type="checkbox" name="bookChoice3" value="Fantasy">Fantasy
        <br /><br />

        <input type="textarea" name="textarea"/>
        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you aren't preventing the submit

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problmes...

1. the validate method must return false if the validation fails
2. There is no element with ID userName

Try

```
<form name="userSurvey" onsubmit="return validName()">
```

then

```
function validName() {
    var Name = document.userSurvey.userName.value;
    if (Name == "") {
        alert("Please enter your name.");
        document.userSurvey.userName.focus();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8BLEF/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked great!

Answer (score 0):

When you have a problem like this you should make it easier for others to help you.

e.g. you could have put this up as a JSFiddle, which I have done for you this time.

See http://jsfiddle.net/anaran/eA4eW/

I have also incorporated the fixes already.

The fix shown above, and following one:

```
    <input type="text" size="30" name="userName" id="userName" />
```